# awk : compare 2 files with 2 columns

Tags: awk

i have to compare 2 files using awk.
        The structure of each files is the same : path checksum

File1.txt

```
/content/cr444/commun/      50d174f143d115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb91
/content/cr764/commun/     10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb91
/content/cr999/commun/     10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbbpp
```

File2.txt

```
/content/cr555/test/        51d174f14f6115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb91
/content/cr764/commun/     10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb78
/content/cr999/commun/     10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbbpp
```

Result expected is a .csv (with separator |):

```
/content/cr444/commun/|50d174f143d115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb91||not in file2
/content/cr555/test/||51d174f14f6115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb91|not in file1 
/content/cr999/commun/|10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbbpp|10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbbpp|same checksum
/content/cr764/commun||10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb91|10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb78|not same checksum
```

Comment: If your separator is `|`, is it really **C**SV output?

Comment: @Shawn some people these days are referring to the `C` in `CSV` as `Character` rather than `Comma`. In fact in SO that's how CSV is defined, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/csv/info. I'm still trying to get used to it - just one more layer of ambiguity around "what is a CSV"! :-).

Comment: @tony The last line, should it read `/|` instead of `||`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the order of output lines is not important. Then you could:

1. Collect lines from `File1.txt` into an indexed array (`$1 -> $2`)
2. Process lines from `File2.txt`:

   1. If `$1` is in the indexed array from (1) compare their checksums and print accordingly
   2. If `$1` is not in the indexed array from (1), print accordingly
3. Print all remaining itmes from array (1)

Here's the code:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS="|"} NR==FNR{f1[$1]=$2; next} {if ($1 in f1) { print $1,f1[$1],$2,($2==f1[$1]?"":"not ")"same checksum"; delete f1[$1]} else print $1,"",$2,"not in file1"} END{for (i in f1) print i,f1[i],"","not in file2"}' File1.txt File2.txt
```

Output:

```
/content/cr555/test/|51d174f14f6115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb91|not in file1
/content/cr764/commun/|10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb91|10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb78|not same checksum
/content/cr999/commun/|10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbbpp|10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbbpp|same checksum
/content/cr444/commun/|50d174f143d115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb91||not in file2
```

Answer (score 0):

One way, using [join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html) to merge the two files, and awk to compare the checksums on each line:

```
$ join -a1 -a2 -11 -21 -e XXXX -o 0,1.2,2.2 <(sort -k1 file1.txt) <(sort -k1 file2.txt) |
   awk -v OFS='|' '$2 == "XXXX" { print $1, "", $3, "not in file1"; next }
                   $3 == "XXXX" { print $1, $2, "", "not in file2"; next }
                   $2 == $3 { print $1, $2, $3, "same checksum"; next }
                   { print $1, $2, $3, "not same checksum" }'
/content/cr444/commun/|50d174f143d115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb91||not in file2
/content/cr555/test/||51d174f14f6115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb91|not in file1
/content/cr764/commun/|10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb91|10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbb78|not same checksum
/content/cr999/commun/|10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbbpp|10d174f14fd115b2d12d09c152a2ca59be7fbbpp|same checksum
```